# Printing values of array from an object

Tags: java, arrays

Hi so I have an object that has an array in it however when i try to print the the array itself it prints [Ljava.lang.String;@7637f22

I assume i am not calling it right and would like to know how i may go about doing so?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJfSw.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcnLK.png)

Comment: Please not put images in the question

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(j.controls));
```

this code iterates each element of the array and uses the method toString to show the contentelement.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a method called `Arrays.toString(arr)` that basically prints the array. You would replace `arr` with the actual array name. In other languages such as Python, if you print a list, it prints the contents of it directly. That is not the case in Java. The explanation to why this happens is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)